# Return Sum for Single Day using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am working with a CSV file and I need to return the sum of data for a specific day. Thus far I have been able to break the code into this:

```
import panda as pd
df = pd.read_csv (r'C:Users\ern\Downloads\evergreen.csv')
sum_imps = df['money'].sum() #sum the total of the money column
sumimps_byday = df.groupby(['day'])[["money"]].sum() #groups the sum of the money column by day
```

Now all i need is to be able to take it one step further and rerun the sum of money for a a specific day of my choosing. I don't think this is too hard, just drawing a blank.

Comment: You need to provide some sample data.

Comment: @johnbowen did you check my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us define `df` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = [['day1', 2900, 3000], ['day2', 3300, 3350], ['day3', 3200, 3150], ['day1', 3200, 3050]], columns = 'day, money, close'.split(', '))
```

Here is what `df` looks like.

```
df
>>>
     day    money   close
0   day1    2900    3000
1   day2    3300    3350
2   day3    3200    3150
3   day1    3200    3050
```

Suppose I want to get the `sum` of **money** for `day` which we can easily see to be 6100, I would do the following.

```
df[df.day == 'day1']['money'].sum()
>>>6100
```

Answer (score 1):

```
total_money = df.loc[df['day'] == '20/03/2019', 'money'].sum()
```

should do the trick.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'day': ['20/03/2019', '21/03/2019', '20/03/2019'],
                   'money': [1, 5, 7]})
print(df)

print('Total money for 20/03/2019: ' + str(df.loc[df['day'] == '20/03/2019', 'money'].sum()))
```

should give the desired output

```
          day  money
0  20/03/2019      1
1  21/03/2019      5
2  20/03/2019      7
Total money for 20/03/2019: 8
```

Comment: It really shouldn't. That is not an in-place change to a dataframe. What version of pandas?

Comment: Well, your edit now shows the problem. `print()` does _not_ reflect in-place changes to dataframes. I posted a link proving it, you can't run this in REPL; your code does not affect the original df

Comment: And your further edit continues the issue. `print()` is throw-away. Nothing is assigned back to a name that exists in the program so it's as though it never happened.

Comment: @roganjosh This was just an example. The OP does not ask for any in-place changes. Anyway, I've edited my answer to assign the output of the operation to a variable.